# How to create "dynamic" features for a machine learning model using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, feature-extraction

I am preparing data for a machine learning model which makes predictions (target variable not shown below) at CID,transaction_dt level.

I want to create a feature which give me sum of sales (I am calling this dynamic because it changes for each CID,transaction_dt) for each CID before the particular transaction_dt for each CID,transaction_dt combinations.

Similarly I want to create a binary feature for Credit_flag which tells me if the CID used credit card anytime before the transaction date.

**Input**

```
CID transaction_dt  sales   Credit_flag
1000    01-09-15    460         1
1000    01-31-2015  300         0
1000    01-03-15    400         1
1000    01-12-15    240         1
2001    02-06-15    389         1
2001    01-03-15    429         0
2001    04-30-2015  491         0
2001    01-09-15    148  `      1
```

**Desired Output**

Note:pre_sales =sum of sales for the CID before the transaction_dt

```
CID transaction_dt  pre_sales   pre_Credit_flag
1000    01-09-15    400             1
1000    01-31-2015  1100            1
1000    01-03-15    0               0
1000    01-12-15    860             1
2001    02-06-15    577             1
2001    01-03-15    0               0
2001    04-30-2015  966             1
2001    01-09-15    429             0
```

How can I do this elegantly using pandas?
I tried creating a function as shown below but its wont work.

```
def dynamic_var(cid, trans_dt):
    x_data1_dyna=x_data1_dedup[(x_data1_dedup['transaction_dt']<trans_dt) & (x_data1_dedup['cid']==cid)].groupby(['cid','transaction_dt'])\
    .agg({'sales':'sum','credit_flaf':'max'}).reset_index()

    return x_data1_dyna


pd.concat(x_data1_dedup.apply(lambda x: dynamic_car(x['cid'], x['transaction_dt']),axis=1),axis=1)
```

**EDIT**

I am looking for a generic approach which works even if I have 100 columns instead of two columns given here & I want to apply different aggregation logic say, take median for few columns, max for another set of columns, count for another set of columns based on the same transaction_dt logic discussed above?

Comment: Sounds like you want to sort on the date, then use `cumsum` to get a cumulative sum.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a more generic way of doing it. i.e. i have some 100 columns & i want to take median for few columns, max for another set of columns, count for another set of columns based on the same transaction_dt logic discussed above